# Possibility of memory leak risk - getting IntPtr from byte array in c#

Tags: c#, pointers

I am having to use an external DLL to send data to a device. The method I'm using in the DLL takes a pointer to a byte array as a parameter. As I'm using C# I am using the GCHandle.Alloc method to get the memory address and assign it to an IntPtr instance. I then am passing the IntPtr as the parameter. My worry is that there could possibly be a memory leak risk in the code, as I have not used pointers and memory allocation in C# before. The code currently works as shown:

```
GCHandle pinned = GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHAndleType.Pinned);
IntPtr arrayPtr = pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject();

var result = _externalDll.SendInfo(arrayPtr, byteArray.Length);   

pinned.Free();
```

Is this the correct way to assign and use the IntPtr? It seems to work but as this is going to be run about 100 times concurrently each day on a production machine I'd rather avoid any major problems.

Comment: You might not need to do that at all. Can you provide the signature of the function in the external DLL? I assume it's C (or C++ using cdecl)?

Comment: This code is OK, it doesn't produce memory leak. The logic is OK assuming that SendInfo uses arrayPtr synchronously and doesn't store it for future use.

Comment: Another way is: Marshal.AllocHGlobal + Marshal.Copy + SendInfo + Marshal.FreeHGlobal. This way allows to avoid pinning, but adds copy operation.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the signature, just some documentation (which defines it as: SendInfo (char* table, int bytes)) and an email with the developer where he confirms it should be a byte[]* not a char*. I suspect Stephen Martin is probably correct and I'd be able to just pass the byte array and let the runtime do the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the only time you need to use a **GCHandle** is when the unmanaged code will be keeping a reference to your pointer for later use.

Here you just seem to be passing in the pointer and then immediately freeing it. If this is the case then you shouldn't be using a **GCHandle** at all. Just make your first parameter a byte[] and pass the byteArray directly. The runtime will take care of pinning the array object for the duration of the call and will pass a pointer to the first element of the array to the unmanaged code.

Comment: This sounds like it'd probably work. I've just been thrown by the function docs asking for a pointer I think. Thanks very much!